# JSON - SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

When I return the value of a AJAX form that submits an API I get this:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token &
```

The AJAX response handling looks like this:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $(".edit_code_lesson").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    result = JSON.parse(data)
    alert(result);
  ).bind "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
    console.log(status + '\n ' + error);
    console.log(xhr);
```

After looking at the `responseText` from the `xhr` I can see the response is:

```
"{&quot;stdout&quot;=&gt;&quot;2\n&quot;, &quot;stderr&quot;=&gt;&quot;&quot;, &quot;wallTime&quot;=&gt;237, &quot;exitCode&quot;=&gt;0}"
```

I am new to HTML so I am unsure if the response should be in HTML. How can I fix this?

NOTE: This is a Rails App using an API wrapper.

Comment: That isn't valid JSON.  You need to make your server not HTML-encode text that isn't being inserted into HTML.

Comment: the response looks like json that has been passed through a funciton that HTML-escapes special characters...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if the HTML entities were corrected*, that still wouldn't be JSON. It would look like this:

```
{"stdout"=>"2\n", "stderr"=>"", "wallTime"=>237, "exitCode"=>0}
```

whereas JSON would look like this:

```
{"stdout": "2\n", "stderr": "", "wallTime": 237, "exitCode": 0}
```

You'll need to fix the server side of this so that: 1. It doesn't do HTML-encoding, and 2. It *does* output JSON, rather than that PHP-like syntax. (If you're using PHP, you can output JSON using [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).)

---

*(* You don't HTML-encode JSON, normally. The only time you might do that would be if you were giving an example of JSON in an HTML page, and wanted to make sure it came out looking right [just like any other text].)*